# Using particle.js in header of page, cannot get to desired size with css

Tags: javascript, css, particle.js

I am using particle.js in just the header area of my page.  I cannot get it to resize to my desired height and width.  I have used canvas sizing, plain heigh and width in css and vh/wh settings.  Nothing seems to change the size of it.  I cannot figure out where it or what it is being controlled by and how to change it. I feel like the answer should be obvious, but I am not getting it.

Here is the hmtl:

```
<body>
<div class="diva">
    <center>
        <div class="divb">

<div id="particles-js"></div> 
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script> 
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html{height: 100%}

body
{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%; min-width: 1037px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;

}
.clear{clear: both;}
.left{float: left;}
.right{float: right; text-align: right;}
.inner_img{margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; border: 0px;}


/* creates initial containers for entire page */
.diva
{
top: 300px;
width: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;
}


.divb
{
width: 950px;
text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 165px;
}





/* ---- particles.js container ---- */ 

#particles-js { 
 display: block;
 width: 950px;
 height: 200 px;
 background-color: white;
 background-image: url("http://celt.MiamiOH.edu/lillycon/images/lillylogo2017.png");
 background-position: bottom;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Comment: Your `height` value in `#particles-js` is invalid: `height: 200 px;` <-- eliminate the space

Comment: Oh, good grief. Thank you so much!  I knew the answer was obvious, but didn't realize how much.  I can't believe I have stared at that for hours and didn't see the space.